# Google doc file style not preserved when updated

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to create a google doc file and fill it with content from html.
Html contains large table element, so to fit it page orientation of google doc must be landscaped. First I am creating google file using Docs API, change its page style to landscape,
and then trying to update this doc file using drive api. But when I do so the style goes back to portrait and html table does not fit to one page.
So basically I want the google doc file to not change its style,
or apply needed style before updating.Is there a way to do that?

**My code**

//drive service

```
class DriveService(){
fun getService(): Drive {

   private val httpTransport: NetHttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
   private val jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

   return Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, getCredentials())
            .setApplicationName(applicationName)
            .build()

}
}
```

//update google doc file

```
val fileMetadata = File()
val filePath: java.io.File = ClassPathResource("files/index.html").file
val mediaContent = FileContent("text/html", filePath)
driveService.getService().files().update(
            "google doc file id",fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .execute()
```

The part of code where I create google doc and changing style works fine, so I don't include it here.

**UPDATE:**

// google credentials

```
  fun getCredentials(): com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential {
        val classPathResource = ClassPathResource(p12FilePath)

        val jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()

        return GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(classPathResource.inputStream)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(setOf(DocsScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DocsScopes.DRIVE, DocsScopes.DOCUMENTS))
            .setServiceAccountUser(email)
            .build()
    }
```

Comment: Hey @noors, is there any particular reason you are using the Drive API update method in this situation? Can you confirm the page style was created successfully as well? I tried to update a Google doc set in landscape mode but I was able to do that successfully.

Comment: @ale13 the reason I am using Drive API is because I need to import content from html file. Yes I confirm that I am able to change page style using Docs API

Comment: "Yes I confirm that I am able to change page style using Docs API" - so the issue you are encountering is when using the Drive API then? Can you provide a list of all the requests you are making?

Comment: yes, the above code is all I have related to Drive API in my project so far. To reproduce the problem  1) create google doc file with some text  2) change its page orientation to landscape 3) get Id of this doc  4) execute above code using id 5) check page orientation of document - in my case its changing back to portrait, which is not what I need